# Proof of having an eTA to fly to Canada

Tags: air-travel, canada, eta

I am flying to Canada and have an eTA linked to my passport. Can I now just present my passport at the check-in desk?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

> When we approve your eTA, it will be
>   linked to the passport you used to apply. You need to present this
>   passport when you check-in to your flight to Canada.
>
> The airline staff will scan your passport to confirm that you have a
>   valid eTA. If you do not have one, you won’t be able to board your
>   flight.

Source:
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html